# jquery 2 iframes back button problem

Tags: jquery

Hi i have the following problem. I have in a page two iframes. The "gmap" iframe and the "bframe" iframe. I have created a back button and i want it to control only the bframe. Assume i have visited some links in the bframe and a link at the gmap iframe and i hit the back button. Then the gmap frame loads the previws link and not the bframe iframe. 
The code is below:
  
   var frame    = self.frames['bframe'];
$("#bck a").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                frame.history.back();
        });

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin might help you out, http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/